Massive insertion with JMeter and oracle sql
Basically, I have a dump file with lots of rows of data and I'm testing what transaction values ​​per second I can get. My goal was to reach, for example, 20,000 transactions per second, but I can't exceed 7,000. (Also i'm runing the test plan for about 16 mins and inserting around 7 milions of lines).
In JMeter I'm playing with the number of threads but I did a test with 100 threads and another with 32 and the results are practically the same.
What do you recommend doing to get close to 20,000 transactions per second?
The table where I'm inserting the data still has some indexes and foreign keys (I don't know if it's worth mentioning but as it impacts performance I thought it would be worth saying)
My insert script looks like this:
INSERT INTO HR.EMPLOYEES (
    EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, EMAIL,
    PHONE_NUMBER, HIRE_DATE, JOB_ID, SALARY, 
    COMMISSION_PCT, MANAGER_ID, DEPARTMENT_ID)
VALUES (
    ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 
    TO_DATE(?, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), ?, ?, 
    nullif(?, 'null'), ?, ?)

Until now i only tried to change the threads count. I read something about batch inserts but i dn't know how to setup this on JMeter. I'm knew tos this kind of stuff.

those indexes and foreign keys are often a bottleneck. If you want to get the load performance at its max, load a table that has no indexes or foreign keys. Next convert your code from row-by-row to array bind so you have fewer network round trips. If "jmeter" (I haven't heard of it) can do this, great. If not, consider a different tool that can.

The thing is, for the sake of the challenge i should not delete indexes and neither the foreign keys. I think i have to find a optimal JMeter test plan, either using loops or play around with the threads count or something like that, I just don't know what i should do and what it's good practices performance wise...
It can also be a database performance problem, but i think can't change the table configurations (like deleting indexes and stuff)

What is the bottleneck when you run?  It is possible that there is a bottleneck in the database that would need to be resolved.  It is possible that there is a bottleneck on the local machine running JMeter where it can't send data any faster to the database and you need to run the process on multiple client machines.

@JustinCave basically this a challenge and is for analysis purpose. Both the JMeter and the PDB where i'm in working are locally on my computer. How should i monitor the database after executing the JMeter test plan to search for the possible botleneck ?

Is there some reason to believe that 20,000 transactions per second when both client and database are running on a single machine is achievable?  Batching inserts would increase the number of rows you could insert but not the number of transactions.  An AWR report would show you what the database was waiting on but you'd probably need to combine that with OS performance tools to see what resources JMeter was consuming vs what resources the database was consuming.

@JustinCave well, just because that's what is written on the challenge statement, and because it was already done by other people. Ok so batching is not necessarily the fixing method, i didn't knew if it would help the number of transactions per second or not, that's why i mentioned it.
I'm going to try to monitor what is happening on the database while the JMeter test plan is executing the mass insertion

What exactly do you mean by "challenge statement"?  Is this, say, a homework assignment where everyone is using a standardized machine setup?  Or is this some sort of tutorial where people are using very different setups, some with separate client and server machines?

Sorry, I thought you were trying to solve a real business problem. The best way to learn from programming classes in school is to come up with solution ideas yourself and try them.

@MartimFernandes So I assume it would be "cheating" if you were to do things like drop indexes, disable constraints, batch inserts, use direct-path writes (which avoids expensive logging at the expense of durability), and other data warehouse tricks that could load the entire file in 1 second. If you're replicating an OLTP environment, you can never relax those constraints and potentially load bad data. But are you allowed to modify your primary key to use a scalable sequence?

@MartimFernandes In my real-world experience with similar scenarios, scalable sequences are the key to good performance for massively parallel, tiny transactions. However, they wouldn't perfectly fit with your data, since the EMPLOYEE_ID is part of your data. But you could argue that high-performance systems should let the database generate synthetic primary keys. Scalable sequences use prefixes to avoid hot blocks (multiple sessions writing to the same index block) while improving caching (the same session uses the same block). The PK index write is often the bottleneck in these situations.

yeah, it is as you said @JonHeller. But yeah, i can suggest the usage of scalable sequence. I just have to explain why i choose that and prove it by testing. The goal here is to improve the mass insertion to achieve the 20 000 transactions per second. I just have to fundament any choice i make!
I will go look into scalable sequences and test it, to see what impact has on the mass insertion. Than i will check if I rly need to import the Employee_id from the .csv dump file or if i can use the scalable sequence.
Thank you all for the help!

@JonHeller i found out what was the bottleneck for my scenario. Basically the database is pending a lot with Log file sync, which i think is due to the auto commit config of the jmeter test plan.
I'm now searching for a way to make the commit only after a certain number of commits or only at the end of the test, i still don't know what it's possible or not in JMeter, but i think fixing the way the commits are happening will get me the desired throughput   of 20 000 transactions per second

@MartimFernandes - Note that, by definition, if you do fewer commits, you are doing fewer transactions per second.  You can likely easily insert 20,000 rows per second in a single transaction.  It is vastly more difficult to do 20,000 transactions per second each inserting a single row.  If you are actually concerned about rows per second not transactions per second, then batching the inserts would be back on the table.

@MartimFernandes Disabling the per-row commits should improve performance but is also kind of cheating arguably, since a real-life application would commit after every transaction. Alternatively, you can try setting the parameters COMMIT_LOGGING and and COMMIT_WAIT. Those parameters also sacrifice durability for performance. And, if possible, you could try to put just the redo logs on a faster storage device.


First make sure that the software running on your machine is not a bottleneck.

Monitor the operating system baseline health metrics (CPU, RAM, Network, Disk, Swap) on your machine. The majority of operating systems have built-in tools for this. Also it could also be good to monitor JVM metrics like Heap usage and GC frequency/time using i.e. JVisualVM.

But based on the discussion from the comments of your question, that does not seem to be the issue.
I have not personally tried it, but I think this other StackOverflow post might have the answer your are looking for in order to do fewer commits with more rows bundled into a single transaction: JMeter JDBC manual commit

If the out-of-the-box JDBC sampler implementation (with the provided options) does not fit your specific needs or does not provide you with enough flexibility, JMeter is pretty flexible so you can directly write the Database connection code and SQL commands inside a JSR223 Sampler test element, just like you'd write code in any IDE (using Groovy or Java code). Then this JSR223 Sampler will execute just like any other Sampler in JMeter, following the built-in Test Plan Execution order.


